How to print last row of items when printing a row of x items per line?
I have a sorted List<T[]>. The problem comes when I try to print the last row of items for each
T[]. Because the last row maybe less than x per row, the rows end up not being grouped as intended.
Expected Output:

0001    0002    0004    0007    0011    0014    0015    0016    0017    0018
0019    0022    0023    0025    0026    0027    0029    0034    0035    0038
0039    0046    0048    0049    0056    0058    0059    0077    0088    0089
0099    0112    0113    0114    0116    0117    0118    0122    0123    0124
0126    0127    0133    0134    0136    0137    0138    0139    0145    0146
0147    0148    0149    0156    0157    0158    0159    0167    0168    0189
0223    0225    0226    0228    0229    0234    0235    0237    0238    0239
0244    0245    0246    0247    0248    0249    0256    0257    0258    0269
0277    0278    0289    0333    0335    0336    0338    0339    0344    0345
0346    0347    0349    0357    0358    0359    0366    0368    0379    0389
0399    0444    0446    0447    0449    0455    0456    0457    0459    0467
0468    0469    0477    0478    0479    0488    0489    0499    0556    0557
0566    0567    0568    0579    0588    0589    0666    0667    0669    0679
0689    0777    0779    0789    0799    0889   
 
1119    1124    1126    1129    1133    1134    1138    1145    1146    1147    
1148    1149    1156    1158    1167    1168    1169    1179    1189    1199    
1225    1227    1233    1234    1235    1237    1238    1244    1245    1247    
1248    1249    1255    1256    1257    1258    1259    1266    1267    1268    
1269    1277    1278    1279    1288    1289    1299    1336    1338    1339    
1345    1346    1347    1348    1349    1355    1356    1358    1359    1366    
1367    1368    1369    1378    1379    1445    1446    1447    1449    1455    
1456    1457    1458    1468    1469    1479    1489    1499    1558    1566    
1567    1568    1578    1579    1589    1599    1667    1677    1678    1679    
1689    1789    1888    1889


1999    2224    2225    2235    2238    2239    2246    2249    2256    2257
2266    2267    2268    2269    2278    2279    2333    2337    2339    2344
2346    2347    2348    2355    2356    2357    2358    2366    2368    2369
2378    2389    2399    2445    2446    2448    2457    2458    2459    2467
2468    2469    2477    2478    2479    2488    2499    2557    2567    2568
2569    2577    2588    2589    2667    2679    2688    2699    2789    2889


3334    3345    3346    3356    3357    3358    3366    3367    3369    3378
3379    3389    3444    3445    3447    3449    3455    3456    3457    3459
3467    3468    3469    3477    3478    3479    3489    3499    3555    3556
3568    3569    3577    3578    3579    3589    3668    3678    3689    3699
3778    3779    3788    3789    3799  

  
4446    4448    4456    4457    4458    4466    4467    4469    4477    4479    
4556    4559    4566    4568    4569    4578    4579    4599    4666    4667    
4668    4678    4679    4688    4689    4699    4778    4779    4788    4789    
4799    4888    4889 
   

5555    5556    5557    5566    5568    5569    5579    5589    5599    5668    
5669    5678    5679    5689    5699    5777    5778    5789    5799    


6678    6688    6778    6779    6788    6789    6799    6899

    
7779    7789    7799    7888    7899

Actual Output:

0001    0002    0004    0007    0011    0014    0015    0016    0017    0018
0019    0022    0023    0025    0026    0027    0029    0034    0035    0038
0039    0046    0048    0049    0056    0058    0059    0077    0088    0089
0099    0112    0113    0114    0116    0117    0118    0122    0123    0124
0126    0127    0133    0134    0136    0137    0138    0139    0145    0146
0147    0148    0149    0156    0157    0158    0159    0167    0168    0189
0223    0225    0226    0228    0229    0234    0235    0237    0238    0239
0244    0245    0246    0247    0248    0249    0256    0257    0258    0269
0277    0278    0289    0333    0335    0336    0338    0339    0344    0345
0346    0347    0349    0357    0358    0359    0366    0368    0379    0389
0399    0444    0446    0447    0449    0455    0456    0457    0459    0467
0468    0469    0477    0478    0479    0488    0489    0499    0556    0557
0566    0567    0568    0579    0588    0589    0666    0667    0669    0679


0689    0777    0779    0789    0799    0889    1119    1124    1126    1129
1133    1134    1138    1145    1146    1147    1148    1149    1156    1158
1167    1168    1169    1179    1189    1199    1225    1227    1233    1234
1235    1237    1238    1244    1245    1247    1248    1249    1255    1256
1257    1258    1259    1266    1267    1268    1269    1277    1278    1279
1288    1289    1299    1336    1338    1339    1345    1346    1347    1348
1349    1355    1356    1358    1359    1366    1367    1368    1369    1378
1379    1445    1446    1447    1449    1455    1456    1457    1458    1468
1469    1479    1489    1499    1558    1566    1567    1568    1578    1579
1589    1599    1667    1677    1678    1679    1689    1789    1888    1889


1999    2224    2225    2235    2238    2239    2246    2249    2256    2257
2266    2267    2268    2269    2278    2279    2333    2337    2339    2344
2346    2347    2348    2355    2356    2357    2358    2366    2368    2369
2378    2389    2399    2445    2446    2448    2457    2458    2459    2467
2468    2469    2477    2478    2479    2488    2499    2557    2567    2568
2569    2577    2588    2589    2667    2679    2688    2699    2789    2889


3334    3345    3346    3356    3357    3358    3366    3367    3369    3378
3379    3389    3444    3445    3447    3449    3455    3456    3457    3459
3467    3468    3469    3477    3478    3479    3489    3499    3555    3556
3568    3569    3577    3578    3579    3589    3668    3678    3689    3699


3778    3779    3788    3789    3799    4446    4448    4456    4457    4458
4466    4467    4469    4477    4479    4556    4559    4566    4568    4569
4578    4579    4599    4666    4667    4668    4678    4679    4688    4689


4699    4778    4779    4788    4789    4799    4888    4889    5555    5556
5557    5566    5568    5569    5579    5589    5599    5668    5669    5678


5679    5689    5699    5777    5778    5789    5799    6678    6688    6778


6779    6788    6789    6799    6899    7779    7789    7799    7888    7899

What I have tried and gotten stuck:
List<T> li = new List<T>();   
       
foreach (T[] group in groups)
{
    int index = 0;
    do
    {
        count++;
        if (count <= rowCount)
        {
            li.Add(group[index]);
            if (count == 10)
            {                           
                line = string.Join("\t", li);

                Console.WriteLine(line);

                count = 0;
                line = "";

                li.Clear();
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
    while (index <group.Length);
}


After the while add if (li.Count > 0) { Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", li)); li.Clear();

What you want is Enumerable.Chunk():
foreach (T[] group in groups)
{
    foreach(var chunk in group.Chunk(10))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", chunk));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

That's it... that's the whole thing. See it here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ahe3LX


Just in case it matters to OP: Enumerable.Chunk assumes .NET 6 or later

Wow, that makes it a whole lot easier. Thanks everyone for the help.

You are most of the way there. You just need to flush your buffer between groups.
After your do-while loop finishes, if there is anything left in li, do exactly the same thing you did when count == 10.
